# Не могу добавить запись в таблицу Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Пытаюсь реализовать добавление записи в таблицу `sotrudnik` через `Hibernate`. Таблица `sotrudnik` связана с таблицей `otdel` по полю `otdelenie_id`. При добавлении выходит ошибка:

> Could not determine type for: models.Otdel, at table: sotrudnik, for
> columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(otdel)]

С чем это связано, что не так я настроил?

Класс Sotrudnik.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sotrudnik")
public class Sotrudnik {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String fio;

    @Column
    private int otdelenie_id;

    private Otdel otdel;

    public Sotrudnik() {    }

    public Sotrudnik(String fio, int otdelenie_id) {
        this.fio = fio;
        this.otdelenie_id = otdelenie_id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "otdelenie_id")
    public Otdel getOtdel() {
        return otdel;
    }

    public void setOtdel(Otdel otdel) {  this.otdel = otdel;  }

    public int getId() {   return id;    }

    public void setId(int id) {        this.id = id;    }

    public String getFio() {        return fio;    }

    public void setFio(String fio) {        this.fio = fio;    }

    public int getOtdelenie_id() {        return otdelenie_id;    }

    public void setOtdelenie_id(int otdelenie_id) {        this.otdelenie_id = otdelenie_id;    }
}
```

Класс Otdel.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "otdel")
public class Otdel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String text;

    private List<Sotrudnik> sotrudnikList = new ArrayList<Sotrudnik>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "otdel")
    public List<Sotrudnik> getSotrudnikList() {
        return sotrudnikList;
    }

    public void setSotrudnikList(List<Sotrudnik> sotrudnikList) {        this.sotrudnikList = sotrudnikList;    }

    public Otdel() {    }

    public Otdel(String text) {        this.text = text;    }

    public String getText() {        return text;    }

    public void setText(String text) {        this.text = text;    }

    public int getId() {        return id;    }

    public void setId(int id) {        this.id = id;    }
}
```

Класс OtdelDao

```
public class OtdelDao {
    public void save(Otdel otdel) {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(otdel);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Класс SotrudnikDao

```
public class SotrudnikDao {
    public void save(Sotrudnik s) {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(s);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Main.class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sotrudnik sotrudnik = new Sotrudnik("Test", 1);

        SotrudnikDao sotrudnikDao = new SotrudnikDao();

        sotrudnikDao.save(sotrudnik);

    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: models.Otdel, at table: sotrudnik, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(otdel)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:512)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:625)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728)
    at utils.HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.java:23)
    at dao.SotrudnikDao.save(SotrudnikDao.java:10)
    at start.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.SotrudnikDao.save(SotrudnikDao.java:10)
    at start.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае Вам не нужно у сотрудника поле `private private int otdelenie_id;`

Вместо этого напишите

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "otdelenie_id")
private Otdel otdel;
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column - вот тут почитайте

Comment: Пытался так,  в таком случае выходит ошибка "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: значение NULL в столбце "otdelenie_id" отношения "sotrudnik" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL" потому что в таблице sotrudnik поле otdelenie_id остается пустым и не не знаю что туда писать при добавлении нового сотрудника.

Comment: Так чтобы добавить сотрудника отдел должен уже существовать, раз у Вас такое ограничение стоит. А писать в otdelenie_id нужно id существующего отделаю

Comment: PS. Я бы переименовал otdelenie_id в otdel_id или класс Otdel в Otdelenie. А то потом по мере роста проекта запутаетесь.

Comment: Т.е. мне нужно получить id существующего отделения. Затем при создании сотрудника через sotrudnik.setOtdelenie указать id отделения?

Comment: Именно так, раз у Вас не бывает сотрудников без отделения. Или можно не id, а отделение целиком - public Sotrudnik(String fio,Otdel otdelenie) {...}. Сорри! Только так и можно. id не прокатит - Вам его ставить некуда

Comment: А структура таблицы sotrudnik при этом должна поменяться?

Comment: Если решите переименовать otdelenie_id в otdel_id - то имя столбца конечно нужно поменять в таблице

Comment: Это да. Я про другое спрашивал. Если передавать Sotrudnik(String fio,Otdel otdelenie), то при записи сотрудника в базу из Otdelenie будет браться  его id и записываться в поле itdelenie_id?

Comment: Вот так сделал: OtdelDao otdelDao = new OtdelDao();
        Otdel otdel1 = otdelDao.findByID(1);
        Sotrudnik sotrudnik = new Sotrudnik("Test", otdel1);
        SotrudnikDao sotrudnikDao = new SotrudnikDao();
        sotrudnikDao.save(sotrudnik);

Пишет ошибку Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: otdel, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(sotrudnikList)]

Comment: Заработало убрав из класса Otdel сведения о сотруднике

Answer (score 0):

Создание сотрудника подразумевает наличие отдела, так как сотрудника без отдела просто быть не может. А вот отдел может быть без сотрудников (не наняли и т.п.).

Поэтому сначала создайте отдел, а затем уже сотрудника.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).